# Angular2: Initialize a parameter on an injectable

Tags: angular

I'm developing a library in order to get access to a REST ednpoint.

I've generated a Injectable class foreach REST endpoint (you can take a look on [here](https://github.com/jeusdi/swagger-client/blob/master/src/api/UsersApi.ts). Now, I need to add OAuth dance to this callings, and I've thought to create a `OAuthService` class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

import { OAuthSettings } from './OAuthSettings';

@Injectable()
export class OAuthService
{
    constructor(private http: Http, private settings: OAuthSettings) { }

    grantAuthorization() {}

    getAccessToken() {}

    refreshAccessToken() {}
}
```

, where `OAuthSettings` is:

```
export class OAuthSettings {
    baseAuthzURI: string;
    baseCESTURI: string;

    client: string;
    user: string;
    passwd: string;

    authzCode: string;
    accessToken: string;
    refreshToken: string;
    authCodeThreshold: Date;
    accessTokenThreshold: Date;
    refreshTokenThreshold: Date;
}
```

I'm able to figure out that I need to add an `OAuthService` on `UserApi` as dependency. But, what about `OAuthSettings`, how is this provided, or initialized?

This library it's used by an application which's going to need to provide an user and a password. So, these fields have to be provided on `OAuthSettings` by someway.

Comment: Add a method to `OAuthService` which returns the settings for that instance.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not able to figure out what you are trying to mean. I've edited the post and I've added user and password are unknown until an app (which's using my library) read it from any form.

Comment: @Jordi: edit your title (anGular, not anDular)

Answer (score 2):

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [{ provide: OAuthSettings, useValue: {...}}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Günter. Please, could you expand a bit your answer taking these gists: [LoginModule.ts](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/67676b50692ee9f2ed2e92acadd86826), and [LoginComponent.ts](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/f9a518865732b8e7699896e089d567ff) and [LoginTemplate](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/9a45d0bf393bab677537795cee2edf16)? I'm really a newbie with angular2 and it really would help me a bit better.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how these gists are related. You need to register a provider then DI can inject it to other services, components, ...

Comment: Where do I need to add this annotation: on root module or on login module?

Comment: On any module that is imported somewhere and that is not lazy loaded.